# CSS for iPad/Safari is being used by small-screen laptops

Tags: css, ipad, safari

We're using the following HTML meta tag and style query to allow us to target the iPad/Safari browser (for a few minor variations in the iPad compared to windows/linux browsers):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="style/tablet.css" />
```

But the tablet.css file is also being loaded on smaller laptops (ie, those with less than 1024px) - and also seems to come into play when zooming in on larger screens, too.

Using device width is not a very good way of discriminating an actual device/browser, but all my hunting on the internet says that this is the best way to do it.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to revert to javascript for this

You could either use modernizr to detect touch event support

http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html

Modernizr will add a class to the `<html>` tag so you can target touch supporting devices quite easy.

Or detect the user agent with javascript if you want more accuracy, but it would need regular updating for updates and new tablet OS releases.

Comment: I think the modernizr touch tests will be the way to go - a mix of that and screen size will help us target adaptations for tablets and phones. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Making your @media query a little more fine grain will help weed-out unwanted devices/browsers better:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="style/tablet.css" />
```

Using `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:` and `orientation` is much more specific to iPad/Phone than screen dimensions.

Comment: what about when the ipad is in landscape?

Comment: requiring orientation alone should eliminate all desktop/laptop browsers, as they don't have that function. Pixel-ratio 2 is specific to retina displays

Comment: My goal is essentially narrow the window so small that if anything should get in, 99% of the time, I can assume it's a i-device. Apple's CSS reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007601-SW1